# Sorting, Paging in the Repository pattern & loosely coupled

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, language-agnostic, repository

I have a `SalesmanRepository` that simply lists all the salesmen from my database. 
I want to display the result in a grid (imagine a Web interface), so the user can display or hide any field, sort a column and use paging.

Let's assume I have a very large set, so the sorting and paging **must** be server-side.

My question is, how can I stay loosely-coupled in my architecture?

1. I don't want my database column's name to the binded to the UI's columns. I want to have the flexibility to change for a new type of database later.
2. How should I handle paging? By adding parameters such as `page` and `numberOfItemsPerPage` directly to the repository's method for example?
3. How should I approach sorting as well? I don't want either to bind the database column's name to the sorting parameter, as in I could have a new type of database and I would break all my software.

Basically, how can I approach these concept and stay loosely coupled? Ideally, I would like a language-agnostic approach, but I'm using `C#` if there is a better language-specific answer.

---

**EDIT** : My question can be more precise as is: how can I tell my repository to sort by a field, without mentioning the name of the field directly?

---

**EDIT 2**: I want to tell my repository to sort by a field, but I don't want to be binded to the implementation since the interface of my Repository is in my business logic layer (or domain layer).

Let's assume I have a MySQL database (hence a `SalesmanMySQLRepository`) with a table named `Salesman` that includes a column `Name`.

Let's say now that I also have a SQL Server database (with a `SalesmanSQLRepository`) with a table named `Salesman` that includes the same column `Name`, but here I would name it instead `BobbyName` because my team decided to have some sort of prefix at columns for whatever reason. It is detail-specific and has nothing to do with business logic.

How is my `SalesmanRepository` should look like? I don't want to send a string directly as in each implementation is completely different. I guess there would be a method like `PagedResult<Salesman> List(SortingParameter field)`, but how should I handle this parameter?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for another abstraction in a ViewModel between your data models and views?

Comment: Can you guide me on how a ViewModel will help me through sorting and paging?

Comment: Incase of small datasets you shouldn't worry about pageSzie or any other filters or sorting in Repository, instead controller (MVC pattern) should handle paging, sorting or filtering. Incase of large datasets, i would use OData (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api), expose data as service

Comment: How is any system supposed to know what to sort by, if you don't tell it -- at some point -- what to sort by?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. One solution I've found was to declare an enum with fields available for sorting. I don't know if there is some sort of a strategy pattern as well or whatever, I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I did it once. I resolved this issue by creating a object like:

```
public class ClientPage
{
    private int PageIndex;
    private int PageLengh;
    private List<Client> Clients;
    private int ClientsCount;
}
```

So I could manage pages instead of clients list.

Hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: I understand, I could have a `PagedResult<E>`. But now, I still need to resolve my _sorting_ problem.

Comment: I didn't understand your sorting problem. Do you want a sort algorithm only or a way to to page all sorting set brought from db? I'll assume second choice. For this, I suggest you to store all data sorted in server memory so you can send in parts to client. PageIndex and PageLenght are for this purpose. For ex, if your list has 10 data and you and to send 3 by 3 you should start send a client page with index 1 length 3 with three first data, then second page would have index 4 length 3, and so on... Hope this helps

Comment: Let's assume I have a million entries. If I want the first n entries of page 1 ordered by the field "Name" (for example), I can't fetch the first n entries then sort client-side, since it will simply sort the fetched entries. I need to sort them server-side. That being said, I know my column name in my database is named "Name" as well, but I would like to find a way to stay loosely coupled. I don't want my business logic to send a string "Name" through my Repository, and use that string directly in my implementation. I'm looking for a loosely-coupled solution.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you don't want paging and sorting on both client and database, so, i think the only place you can do paging and sorting is in memory, so you can code a shared method like

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SortingAndPaging<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities, int pageSize, int pageNum, string sortField, string order)
{       
   //your sorting and paging logic goes here, maybe Linq is helpful here
}
```

by this, we can achieve Database agnostic

Answer (score 0):

I would solve by sending the text in the column header to the back end as what I want to sort by and then use reflection to find that property name in the object.  You'll need to make sure the display name in the column is convertible to the field name by algorithm or by lookup.  The code below is pseudo-ish, but the method is solid.

Front End:

```
<th class="sortable">Last Name</th> ...
$('.sortable').onClick(function(event){
      //send request to backend with text of header as sortBy
      ...
 });
```

Back End:

```
List<Person> GetPeople ( string sortBy )
{
     //Person has property lastName
     var propery = Person.GetField(SortByStringToPropertyName(sortBy));
     List<Person> people = db.Persons.OrderBy(property).ToList();
     return people;
}
```